# Underwater distance measurement

Tags: sensor, proximity-sensor, distance, waterproof, underwater

I am working on a University project on ROV that needs an underwater distance measurement of about 50 cm min and 2 m max. I tried looking for sensors and came across jsn-sr04t but that doesn't seem to work very well underwater.

I need a cheaper option other than expensive sonar modules which cost hundreds of dollars. Is there any easy workaround to make a cheap reliable sensor that works at a depth of 100 m?

Comment: A telescopic stick.

Comment: What is your budget? You can find ultrasonic depth transducers for pleasure craft for reasonable prices. Many are made by Airmar.

Comment: This can be of interest? https://rwu.pressbooks.pub/webboceanography/chapter/6-4-sound/

Comment: It sounds like this is the part of the project where you actually do some learning. Time for you to do some research and experimentation. By the way, we can't possibly know what "cheap" means to you.

Comment: I agree that ultrasonics is the way to go. That sonar was one of the first active ranging application couldn't be a mistake:P there are sealed transducer for distance measurement optimized for underwater usage, by the way. 'Proper' electronics is tricky, especially the T/R switch, the pulser and the TVA (the major pieces). Luckily they have been integrated (TI makes some and Microchip acquired one of the biggest specialists). Prepare to do a lot of impedance matching *both* electrical and mechanical

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio Do you think there is a way to make the JSN-SR04t waterproof in such a way that it works at such deeper levels?

Comment: @StarCat I am thinking about 10-15 dollars

Comment: There is some SR04 (only one sensor Tx/Rx) that are waterproof ... but not probably at so much deeper levels. Take into account also "propagation" speed ...

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio It is worth noting that the acoustic impedance of FR4 is reasonably close to the geometric mean of that of water and common PZT ceramics... Think 1/4 wave line. It is usual to provide some means to calibrate the thing at depth, either a separate transducer pair a known distance apart or some sort of mechanical target that you can hit with the beam. At 100M you will discover more ways then you would ever imagine for water to get into a supposedly sealed vessel.

Comment: Well, I suppose that most 'waterproof' transducers are only for rains and splashes, not for 100m water pressure. In the 10-15 dollar range I can't think of anything however, with the related circuitry I'd spend at least double of that. http://www.prowave.com.tw/english/products/ut/uwtx/uwtx.htm for example is supposedly rated for… 5m underwater

Comment: Perhaps DIY with something like this "40khz 50w ultrasonic transducer"  https://fr.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-40khz-50w-ultrasonic-transducer.html or this https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/4001095609591.html?spm=a2g0o.search0304.0.0.fd6c7674VuM0Cg&algo_pvid=56331b44-c2b0-4c44-b637-67b58edbca14&algo_exp_id=56331b44-c2b0-4c44-b637-67b58edbca14-12

Comment: @Antonio51 I was thinking the same, but would it be a reliable solution

Comment: Know the characteristics of the component well. If the "assembly" of the sensor (as waterproof as possible) is "transparent" to UltraSounds, the sensor should be able to operate in transmission/reception. A driver transformer (up) with the "protection circuitry" (usually R+ 2 diodes) for the receiving part will obviously be needed.

Comment: Something as this https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tuss4440.pdf?ts=1647713234293&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.be%252F

Comment: Or this for high power (Tx) https://www.bjultrasonic.com/shop/40khz-50w-ultrasonic-transducer-40khz-50w-ultrasonic-generator/ but with some "adjust".